# Passing a component of a pointer by value

Tags: rust

I've just started out with Rust, so some of my concepts may be wrong. I'd really appreciate corrections if this is the case.

I was following the [lifetimes guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/guide-lifetimes.html) and trying some of the examples. I modified the rectangle example a little.

I changed the `compute_distance` function to accept `Point` by value in the first parameter.
I then removed the `&` before `on_the_stack.origin` in the call to `compute_distance`.

This gives me the following error:

> cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer

If instead I add the `&` before the `on_the_stack.origin` call as well as accept `Point` by reference in the `compute_distance` function, it works without a hitch.

The second method working makes sense to me, but why does my original approach throw an error?

```
use std::num::Float;

struct Point {
    x : f64,
    y : f64
}

struct Size {w: f64, h: f64}
struct Rectangle {origin: Point, size: Size}

#[cfg(not(test))]
fn main() {
    let on_the_stack = &Rectangle{origin: Point {x: 1.0, y: 2.0},
                                  size: Size {w: 3.0, h: 4.0}};

    let on_the_heap = box Rectangle {origin: Point {x: 5.0, y: 6.0},
                                  size: Size {w: 3.0, h: 4.0}};

    println!("Distance: {}", compute_distance(on_the_stack.origin,&on_the_heap.origin));
}

fn compute_distance ( p1:Point,p2:&Point) -> f64 {
    let x_d = p1.x - p2.x;
    let y_d = p1.y - p2.y;
    Float::sqrt(x_d * x_d + y_d * y_d)
}
```

Comment: I see you linked to the 0.12 docs. Be aware that Rust is quickly changing in preparation for a 1.0 alpha / beta / release. It's recommended to track the nightly builds (and docs).

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. The link on the nightly docs seems to be completely different. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, your changed `compute_distance` wants a *value* as the first parameter. This means that the function is going to take ownership of the argument.

However, you are attempting to pass a smaller piece of a structure (`origin` is embedded in `Rectangle`). To do this, Rust would have to give ownership of *part* of `Rectangle` to the method, but exactly what state would `Rectangle` be left in? A very broken one, so Rust prevents you from doing that. Yay, you didn't shoot yourself in the foot!

"But wait", you say, "it's totally cool if the function gets a *copy* of `origin`". You, as a human, can recognize that and tell the compiler that it's "totally cool":

```
#[deriving(Copy)]
struct Point { /* ... */ }
```

Now Rust knows that it is safe to make a bit-for-bit copy of a `Point` if it would like to. Huzzah!

"But **wait**", you say, "what if it's *not* cool to make a bit-for-bit copy? My structure needs more love than being treated like a bag of bits!". Again, as an intelligent human, you can express that:

```
#[deriving(Clone)]
struct Point { /* ... */ }

// later...

on_the_stack.origin.clone()
```

Now you can make an explicit call (`clone()`) to get a semantic duplicate of the option. Because this could be an expensive operation, the compiler won't do it for you.

**A note on `deriving`**

As I write this answer, `deriving` is transitioning to `derive`. Adjust as needed for your code.

Comment: Haha, thanks a lot for your answer! I learned a new feature that isn't currently on the guide!

Comment: `Copy` used to be implemented automatically by the compiler on types that met certain criteria. This is no longer the case, and that's why one must now write `#[deriving(Copy)]`.